# How to persist an object to a db that contains lists of other objects in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a class `X`. Class `X` contains many lists of different types as shown below. All the lists are child tables in the db.

```
public class X
{
    public List<A> As { get; set; }
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public List<C> Cs { get; set; }
    public List<D> Ds { get; set; }
    public List<E> Es { get; set; }
}
```

My repository takes in an instance of `X` and needs to persist all lists to the db.

```
public void Save(X value)
{
    // Save code here
}
```

What would be my best option to save all the sub lists? Each type in the list maps to a db table. So there is a table in the db for each `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`.

A method for each table that would save the list. Example: `InsertAsById(List<A> values, int id)` and so on. Then call that method within the `Save()`. With this approach, save would look like:

```
public void Save(X value)
{
    InsertAsById(value.As, value.id);
    InsertBsById(value.Bs, value.id);
    // So on for each list.
}
```

We must use ADO.NET. No frameworks.

Comment: Entity Framework does this automatically. May I ask what's the reason not to use it?

Comment: I don't think it will work with our DB (SQLBase). They just recently released a fully managed .net provider, but I'm not sure if it will work with EF or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are limited to using ADO.NET I think there are two routes.

The first would be to use Datasets and a DataAdapter to perform an update (been so long I am not sure the terminology is correct)

The second would be to loop through the records individually and issue insert/updates statements as raw SQL.

You are trying to make a high level operation easy using a lower level framework, many more modern ORMs provide the kind of functionality you need.